# Running all traffic to bypass local firewall

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, firewall

I am on a monitored university network(I live here) and am unable to reach much of the internet, vpn's are also banned, as in they can't establish connection. So I figured I could get a server on linode since I can connect to that, and just tunnel all outgoing data through that. Is that possible? I want all internet using programs to work seamlessly. I am not concerned about encrypting whatever I do.

So far I've tried ssh tunneling but didn't seem to work, when I set up the proxy settings to the ssh tunnel I create using Windows settings, I lose all internet connection (this is on a normal connection to test if what I'm doing works normally). I've gone through ssh related topics and made sure I have an ssh server running on Debian 10 server I'm running.

I've no idea how to achieve what I want, any help would be appreciated. I'm running win11.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct type; when you use the "dynamic tunnel" feature in SSH clients, they provide a SOCKS proxy – but the one you're configuring in Windows is probably expected to be an HTTP proxy.

Both types can be used for the same things (with HTTP proxies being able to handle non-HTTP-based applications using the "CONNECT" request), but they are not interchangeable. Firefox has support for SOCKS proxies in its own settings, but many programs do not.

Not all programs will automatically use a proxy. In particular, anything that runs over UDP *can't* work with either of those types – but also some programs just don't care about proxy settings in general; it's something that each app needs to handle individually and many just don't bother bringing in the SOCKS support code.

You will likely need a VPN tunnel (i.e. an IP-layer "proxy") to handle those situations. Find out what ports and protocols besides SSH are allowed, then set up the appropriate VPN server on your linode. It's somewhat unlikely that your university does DPI, so all usual protocols might work equally well if you can find an unrestricted UDP port for them.

(It is technically possible to use an SSH connection to transport IP in at least two different ways, but both are annoying to set up and only work with Linux/BSD on the client side.)